# Proving an equality in finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $q=3$ and $m=4$, and the map
$$T(a) = a + a^q + a^{q^2} + \cdots + a^{q^{m-1}}$$

We write $F$ the finite field with $q^m$ elements and $K$ the field with $q$ elements.

Proof that $T(\alpha+\beta) = T(\alpha)+T(\beta)$ if $\alpha,\beta \in F$.

I started re-writing $T(a)=a+a^3+a^9+a^{27}$.

Now,  $T(\alpha+\beta)=(\alpha+\beta)+(\alpha+\beta)^3+(\alpha+\beta)^9+(\alpha+\beta)^{27}$.

So $(\alpha+\beta)^3 = \alpha^3 + 3\alpha^2\beta + 3\alpha\beta^2 + \beta^3$. I need the first and last term to make equality occurs, but how can I delete the second and third term? $F$ is a field with $81$ elements, I cannot suppress the terms because ther are $3\cdot t$.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Hint: All fields have either characteristic zero or prime characteristic. In particular, if a finite field $F$ has cardinality $a$ then the the characteristic of $F$ divides $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one field of order 81 (up to isomorphism). Therefore your $F$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{81}$, which is of characteristic $3$. Thus $(a + b)^3 = a^3 + b^3$ holds and you can suppress the terms you want.

Comment: I see... I was confusing characteristic with number of elements. Thanks